# Convert 64bit Binary to Long equivalent

Tags: c#, 64-bit, binary, hex

How can we convert the following 64 bit binary into the long equivalent;

```
01111101 10100011 01001111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11000000  
equals 7D A3 4F FF FF FF FF C0 HEX  
equals 9053167636875050944    << this is the value we want in a C# variable
```

EDIT: The large binary number is currently stored as a String. So its a string to long conversion that I am looking for.

Comment: not quite. just designing a data plugin to read from binary files. just need some help on this part

Comment: You're saying that your file stores one-bit values using characters? Why?

Comment: no, the application of this method is to search through the resulting Byte array (from the file) looking for the byte array which will be generated from BitConverter.GetBytes(longVariableCalculatedAbove)

Comment: My question is "Why are you storing a binary value as a string of 1's and 0's?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint64.aspx

And examples here: http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/09/converting-between-binary-and-decimal-in-c/

Specifically (where bin is a 'binary' string):

```
long l = Convert.ToInt64(bin,2);
```

Comment: Arg! I keep forgetting `Convert`! +1